# Select multiple xml nodes using crossapply

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm currently trying to select multiple nodes for a xml variable that get passed into a stored procedure. But I only get one node from it's xml. How can I list all of the item names and string values?

Test code:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (AllXml ntext)

INSERT @T VALUES('<error>
        <item name="item 1">
        <value string="string 1" />
        </item>
        <item name="item 2">
        <value string="string 2" />
        </item>
        <item name="item 3">
        <value string="string 3" />
        </item>
        </error>')

SELECT 
    CAST(AllXml as xml).value('(/error/item/@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)' ),
    CAST(AllXml as xml).value('(/error/item/value/@string)[1]', 'varchar(max)' )
        FROM @T
```

Desired result:

```
Item 1     string 1
Item 2     string 2
Item 3     string 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using the [CROSS Apply](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx). And `Sub-Select`.

```
SELECT 
    m.c.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Name,
    m.c.value('(value/@string)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS Value
FROM 
     (
        SELECT CAST(AllXml as xml) AllXml 
        FROM @T
     ) AS data
    CROSS APPLY AllXml.nodes('/error/item') as m(c)
```

Or you can use the one more `CROSS APPLY` as below,

```
   SELECT 
        m.c.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Name,
        m.c.value('(value/@string)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS Value
    FROM @T
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(AllXml AS XML)) as D(D)
        CROSS APPLY D.D.nodes('/error/item') as m(c)
```